# Dynamic serving - apache - html, javascript, and .htaccess only

Tags: javascript, html, apache, .htaccess, mobile

I have my desktop site (example.com), and my mobile site (example.com/m/). They both have completely different html files AND stylesheets. I currently have the Desktop site redirecting to the mobile with this script:

```
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||                 
(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
location.replace("/m/");
}
-->
```

But I want it to show the mobile site on mobile, while still showing the desktop site's URL, not the mobile one's. I want the mobile to show (example.com) not (example.com/m/) but display content from (example.com/m/). I've heard this is possible with dynamic serving, but I do not, and do not want a CMS, and I only use HTML, Javascript, and .htaccess, not PHP.

Any ideas?

I've asked this question before, and gotten no answers. Can somebody please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community. I have provided the working example. If it solves your problem do let the other SO user knows by accepting it through clicking the right button near the answer. In case you are struggling with the solution,leave me a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is very much possible using `.htaccess` file.

Below is the working code for same.

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on

  # iPhone or iPad devices
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone|iPod
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/rootfolder\/iphone
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rootfolder/iphone/$1 [NC,L]

  # Android devices
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/rootfolder\/android
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rootfolder/android/$1 [NC,L]

  # Every thing fallback to desktop/common site
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/rootfolder\/desktop
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rootfolder/desktop/$1 [NC,L]
```

The above rule is very much similar to the approach that you are using. We are checking for the user agent. If we find that the user agent is `ipad or ipod` we serve the content from `ipad` specific folder. If it is `android` then from android specific folder and it fallbacks to desktop if nothing is matched.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, except for one thing. I also have Apache set to 302 redirect based on host name for certain domains. After doing this, they still work, but on mobile devices, the redirects don't work, they give a 302 Found error and the moved location is the same as the current page. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can have that RewriteCond in mobile specific rewrites such that in that condition you put that host not equal to the one in which you wanted 302 redirects.

Comment: Thanks. I have gotten it to work. I appreciate your help!